# How to modify Cinnamon desktop drag-drop window size guide

Tags: cinnamon

[image]

As shown in the video above, you can see when I drag a window to the left edge of the desktop, it suggests a window resize up to half of the screen by an overlaying translucent box. And if I drop the window at this point, the window gets resized to exactly half of the screen.

This is a cool feature. And I want to modify its behavior. Instead of the 50% of the screen width, I want it to suggest and take 70% of the screen width from the left edge. And if a window is dragged to the right edge, it should suggest and take 30% of the screen width on drop.

How can I make it possible? I am an experienced Python and Shell programmer. But I have never customized any desktop environment at the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to study C and javascript.

Once you have them in your toolbox, fork https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon and make your own version of the window manager.

Comment: lol. I also know JS and learned C in college. But where to start? What is this feature called?

Comment: It is called "snapping".